# Why doesn't Gaza become Egypt?

Tags: israel, middle-east, egypt, gaza

It seems to me as feasible for Gaza to become part of Egypt as they share the same language, culture, and religion. In turn, Egypt would assume responsibility to control tendencies to attack Israel from within, like Hamas does.

Has subsuming Gaza into Egypt ever been subject of serious diplomatic consideration by an international treaty?

Comment: Has the government of Gaza (Hamas) ever expressed a desire to become part of Egypt? Has the relatively secular government of Hosni Mubarak or Abdelfatah El-Sisi expressed a desire to incorporate a country with a religious government?

Comment: Gaza was administered by Egypt after the first war in 1948 until Israely occupation. That didn't turn out very well for the freedom of the Palestinian people living there, although it was not a formal annexation. Given the current authoritarian rule in Egypt I don't think that this would be what people there are hoping for.